# Graphs in swt exception

Tags: java, graph, swt

i'm trying to create graph using XYGraph, i downloaded the necessary jars and added them to my project but when i write :

```
XYGraph xyGraph= new XYGraph();
```

i get an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Anyone know what the problem is and can help me solve it?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the required Jar files into the classpath

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run your code as a standalone application, but the code transitively depends on the Eclipse RCP libraries. You are able to compile it because your own source code does not directly depend on RCP, but one of the JARs you are using does.

You'll have to find out which JARs from the RCP you need to make your code run. `org.eclipse.core.runtime` is one of the core JARs, and you obviously need it, but this is probably not where it ends.